# If URL contains hash on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run some functions on initial page load and also if the page is refreshed, if the url contains a particular hash.

As of now, I am able to get it working only on page refresh and not working when i first get to the page.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('#story') > -1) {
        alert('true');
    }
});
```

Comment: When you first get to the page is that hash still there?

Comment: Yes, url is http://localhost:8888/pump/#story on first page load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be working with `window.location.hash` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash === '#story') {
        alert('true');
    }
});
```